# Waiting for a condition in an async fn

Tags: rust, async-await

Playing around the async Rust, I'm trying to create an execution loop that gets task descriptions from an `mpsc` channel and performs some processing concurrently in arbitrary order, like this:

```rust
async fn process(receiver: futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver) {
    let mut tasks = FuturesUnordered::new();
    loop {
        futures::select! {
            msg = receiver.recv().fuse() => match msg {
                Ok(MessageFoo) => tasks.push(async { process_foo().await }.boxed()),
                Ok(MessageBar) => tasks.push(async { process_bar().await }.boxed()),
                Err(_) => return
            },
            _ = tasks.select_next_some() => ()
        }
    }
}
```

That works, but if tasks are incoming too fast and processing is slow, a whole lot of futures end up in `tasks` which is not great. To create backpressure, I need no more than N concurrent tasks in `tasks`, and to channel that backpressure, I need to stop `recv()`ing when the queue is full until some future resolves.

My first naive try to implement that was something like

```rust
async fn process(receiver: futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver) {

    async fn add_task(
        tasks: &mut FuturesUnordered<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=()>>>,
        t: Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=()>>>
    ) {
        if tasks.len() < 30 {
            tasks.push(t);
        } else {
            // Else what?!
        }
    }

    let mut tasks = FuturesUnordered::new();

    loop {
        futures::select! {
            msg = receiver.recv().fuse() => match msg {
                Ok(MessageFoo) => add_task(
                    &mut tasks, async { process_foo().await }.boxed()
                ).await,
                Ok(MessageBar) => add_task(
                    &mut tasks, async { process_bar().await }.boxed()
                ).await,
                Err() => return
            },
            _ = tasks.select_next_some() => ()
        }
    }
}
```

And here I'm sitting and scratching my head. Else what? Does it even work like this? Do I need buffered streams instead? Or a wrapper for `FuturesUnordered`? Or something?

Comment: *"Else what?"* well it's your code, you decide what you want to do in that case, pause the task that wants to send with a `sleep`, return the task in an error and let the caller deal with it, silently drop the task, ... there are endless possibilities.

Comment: Typically, I'd use a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) to control concurrency levels

Comment: @cafce25 Well, I'd like to stop `recv()`ing blocking the senders and continue processing as soon as some slot is free. I'm searching for a more idiomatic way to achieve this. Just sleeping in a loop sounds a bit... Low-level-ish for this kind of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the `Receiver` type implements `Stream`, which means you can use stream combinators to describe the behavior you want instead of writing a loop manually.

In particular, [`for_each_concurrent`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.for_each_concurrent) can be used to apply an asynchronous function to each element produced by the stream, running a certain number of such mappings concurrently.  Note that this will stop polling the underlying stream (`receiver`) when the limit has been reached, which accomplishes your goal of applying backpressure when messages are produced faster than they can be processed.

Here is an example of how you might do that.  In this case I set the concurrency limit to 16.

```
use futures::StreamExt;

enum Message {
    MessageFoo,
    MessageBar,
}

async fn process_foo() {}

async fn process_bar() {}

async fn process(receiver: futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<Message>) {
    receiver
        .for_each_concurrent(Some(16), |msg| async move {
            match msg {
                Message::MessageFoo => process_foo().await,
                Message::MessageBar => process_bar().await,
            }
        })
        .await
}
```

Note that this approach also avoids having to box your task futures!

Comment: It took me some time to figure out how to get it to work (as my actual receiver appeared not to implement `Stream`), but in the end, it seems it's exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help!